# Limit the size of a collection in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Say I have an entity like this

```
@Entity
Class A{
//fields

@Onetomany
Set<B> b; // 
}
```

Now, how do I limit the number of 'B's in the collection in such a way that, when there is a new entry in the collection, the oldest one is removed, some thing like [removeEldestEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29) we have in a LinkedHashMap.

I am using MySQL 5.5 DB with Hibernate. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My goal is not to have more than N number of entries in that table at any point of time. 
One solution I have is to use a Set and schedule a job to remove the older entries. But I find it dirty. I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: I don't know whether it is feasible or not but I would use query with `Limit` and `Offset` for such requirement.

Comment: When it comes to JPA you should limit the query which fetches the result not the collection since it will not help if query fetches more result and collection skips it. It will be performance disaster. Now I really don't know whether there is a way in which you can control the query from `Onetomany` annotation. But you can control result using [`setFirstResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) and [`setMaxResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29)

Comment: Please refer my below example that may help you out.

Comment: @AmitD: Yes, that would work in terms of performance. But I will still have stale data in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the code to manually enforce this rule. The main idea is that the collection B should be well encapsulated such that client only can  change its content by a public method (i.e `addB()`) . Simply ensure this rule inside this method (`addB()`) to ensure that the number of entries inside the collection B cannot larger than a value.

A:

```
@Entity
public class A {


    public static int MAX_NUM_B = 4;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<B> b= new LinkedHashSet<B>();

    public void addB(B b) {
        if (this.b.size() == MAX_NUM_B) {
            Iterator<B> it = this.b.iterator();
            it.next();
            it.remove();
        }
        this.b.add(b);
    }

    public Set<B> getB() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.b);
    }
}
```

B:

```
@Entity 
public class B{

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}
```

Main points:

- A should be the owner of the relationship.
- In A , do not simply return B as client can bypass the checking logic implemented in `addB(B b)`  and change its content freely.Instead , return an unmodifiable view of B .
- In @OneToMany , set `orphanRemoval`to true to tell JPA to remove the B 's DB records after its corresponding instances are removed from the B collection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why do we need a bidirectional relationship and and why should the onetomany side be the owner. Isn't that bad coding?

Comment: Yes . You can use the un-directional association . Instead , domain-driven-design recommends to use un-directional association  and eliminate the non-essential association to reduce the complexity .It suggests to keep the association that supports behavior or maintenance of integrity , and removes the association that is only for fulfilling the display requirement.  So whether @OneToMany is bad coding or not depends on the domain

Comment: +1 And you may additionally want to skip the addition if the element being added is already present.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But a bidirectional onetomany relationship with onetomany as the owning side isn't an optimized solution as per the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional).

Comment: Yes.There will be one more update SQL when inserting the "many" side record. But I doubt if it will really make you feel slower just due to this extra update SQL .If you want to get rid of this extra update , you can try to make it as bi-directional association with the "many side" as the owner and setup `B.A` inside `A.addB()`. `B.A` also  cannot be changed outside due to the reasons mentioned above

Comment: I thought I will go for a unidirectional onetomany using a Set. Do you see any caveats in it? Btw thanks for answering my sub questions. :)

Comment: You should pay attention that when the collection B is accessed inside `A.addB()` , whole collection B will be loaded into memory .So if B is very large , it may consume much memory.

Comment: Yes but won't that happen in the solution you have mentioned. Wont Hibernate load the collections to add B? So isn't it more or less the same?

Comment: Looks like I have to load the collections anyways with the above solution, I will see if there is a work around.

Answer (score 2):

There is one API provided by [Apache Commons Collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/). Here you can use the class [CircularFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html) for your reference of the same problem you have, if you want example shown as below that you can achive that

```
Buffer buf = new CircularFifoBuffer(4);
buf.add("A");
buf.add("B");
buf.add("C");
buf.add("D"); //ABCD
buf.add("E"); //BCDE
```

Comment: Is it even remotely related to the problem?

Comment: Well, a FIFO buffer is exactly what the OP described and a buffer is a sort of collection. :-\. (Although a Buffer is not a Set.)

Comment: `Buffer` is not but a collection class that will be useful for storing the value in the collection.

Comment: But I am afraid, If this can be used directly in my case. I am using Hibernate API and I doubt if Hibernate/JPA supports this class as a valid collection. I might have to go for some work around.

Comment: This will work perfectly with your scenario, no work you will have to do regarding this solution and another advantage is that you will not have to manage FIFO thing in your way but API will manage that thing in its own and better way

Comment: As per [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-persistent) this isn't a valid collection implementation for Hibernate. I will have to write a custom implementation.

Comment: I think you should try this, according to me it will not create any problem for you because it implements `Collection` interface of the Collection framework of java, so it will work for you according to my openion

Comment: Yes .Hibernate does not support this collection type. Implement it on your own seems to be a difficult task and not necessary because we can simply ensure this invariant inside the @Entity 's method.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani It doesn't implement Collection Interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to do it manually.

One solution that comes to mind is using `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` event listeners in entity `A`.

Within the method annotated with above annotations , you check if size of `Set<B>` , if it is above the max limit, delete the oldest B entries(which may be tracked by a `created_time` timestamp property of B)

Comment: Thanks. In case of preupdate/prepersist, wont I have to make a call to the DB and check it manually?

Comment: Those events are triggerred only when you save or update entity A. A already have Set<B> fetched.  So you will have to make a db call to remove old `B` s from database, unless you have Cascade Delete for B configured in A entity

Comment: I have read in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) that I cannot invoke EntityManager methods in the callbacks. May be I will have use the Session API there.