# Hibernate annotation for limiting set/list in entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

How to limit list/set in entity?

I have ProfileEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
class Profile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
    @JoinTable(name = "subscriptions", ...)
    var subscriptions: Set<Profile> = emptySet()
}
```

How to limit set?
@Size annotation doesn't work.

Comment: How you used the `@Size`  annotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit the size of a collection in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009119/limit-the-size-of-a-collection-in-jpa)